# Best way to create large static DOM elements in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have many elements that one of my JS widgets needs to create and add to the DOM often. They never change.

So one option would be to store the HTML itself as a string in JS and use JQuery to create the elements from the string, then append it to the document:

```
var elements = "<div><table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table></div>";
function create() {
  return $(elements);
}
$("body").append(create());
```

Another option is to write a function that will use document.createElement("div"), or $("<div>") many times to build the elements, append them to each other where needed, then append to the document:

```
function create() {
  return $("<div>").append($("<table>")......
}
$("body").append(create());
```

In the first case, I have a big JS string that is actually HTML. In the second case, I have an unwieldy piece of JS that actually represents HTML.

Are there (dis)advantages to one or the other? Is there a better solution I'm not thinking of?

Comment: This sounds like a job for a JS templating engine, such as http://handlebarsjs.com/ — unfortunately I don't know enough about it to offer you a real solution, but I think it may be of help.

Comment: @Nix Thanks, stumbled upon this while looking for a way to create complex DOM elements in a manner that was sane and maintainable. handlebars.js is exactly what I needed. :)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

*Note: If you hate reading, just check summary down below for final answer*

Maybe you don't really need to create those with help of jQuery.

If the structure of that html is complicated (hence using document.createElement approach would be an overkill) I would go with `innerHTML` attribute.

```
// somewhere in your code, preferably outside of global scope
var div = document.createElement('div')
div.id = 'mycustomdiv'
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(div);
// assuming elements contains string of html with your elements
div.innerHTML = elements;
```

That way you avoid the (assuming again) unnecessary overhead of creating and wrapping the elements in jQuery object.

---

Update: **test** for yourself what's the fastest method http://jsperf.com/creating-complex-elements. This test confirms that when you're trying to squeeze every last bit of performance revert to vanilla javascript and classic DOM operations.

---

Update 2. To investigate why *innerHTML method* on Firefox 10 have such bad results in relation to passing full string to jQuery.append, I took a look at the jQuery source.

As it turns out (in jQuery 1.7.1), they're using yet another way of creating dom elements by utilizing [document.createDocumentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.createDocumentFragment) (with some fallbacks of course for browsers that don't have proper support).

> DocumentFragments are DOM Nodes. They are never part of the main DOM tree. The usual use case is to create the document fragment, append elements to the document fragment and then append the document fragment to the DOM tree. In the DOM tree, the document fragment is replaced by all its children.
>
> Since the **document fragment** is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it **does not cause page reflow**.

Assuming createDocumentFragment is available it turns out to be the best approach in terms of overall cross-browser performance of script.

So, to sum up:

I stand corrected. **If you're looking for best performance throughout different browsers when creating new DOM elements, focus on document fragments (use jQuery if you don't want to deal with various corner cases yourself).**

For more reading concerning documentFragment check this post on John Resig blog http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: +1 for the summary at the end. I think you should bold that and only that.

Comment: @WTK, I think the test would only be fair if it clears the children after each 25 inserts, because upon reaching the last test the DOM is polluted heavily and the browser is crying already.

Comment: Maybe something like this http://jsperf.com/dquery-vs-jquery-inserting-dom-elements

Answer (score 46):

**Detailed analysis of 3 commons ways of creating DOM in JS and the best approach.**

I will provide 3 ways to create large DOM and their pros and cons, and of-course the most optimized way for large DOM creation and why.
Bottom line is while creating DOM in js, native JS and DOM methods are your friend, don't use Jquery unless there is no other way(which is unlikely).

**Test Data for comparison:** Created 400 rows with 5 columns and appended to DOM.
testData is list of objects that you get from backend in json form to create table.

Attached Execution time test result snapshot for different browsers[image]
**HTML**

```html
<div id="employeeListContainer1"></div>
<table id="employeeList2">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Department</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

***1st way : String Concatenation*** (**Most Optimized way** in terms of performance across browsers)

```js
var tableElementContainer1 = document.getElementById("employeeListContainer1");
var temptableHolder  = '<table><thead><tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Title</th><th>ID</th><th>Department</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

for(var i=0,len=testData.length; i<len; i++){
    temptableHolder  += '<tr><td>' + testData[i].firstName + '</td><td>' + testData[i].lastName + '</td><td>' + testData[i].title
        + '</td><td>' + testData[i].id + '</td><td>'  + testData[i].department +  '</td></tr>';
}

temptableHolder += '</tbody></table>';
tableElementContainer1.innerHTML  = temptableHolder ;
```

Pros:

- Fastest execution time across Firefox/Chrome/IE/Safari **(3 to 5 millisec across browsers)**. Measured via both performance.now() and console.time() APIs.

Cons:

- When number of columns are more and you need to set lot of attributes then working with strings can get little difficult and less maintainable.

***2nd way:  Native Js document.createElement()***(This is 2nd best approach in terms of performance across browsers)

```js
var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
var tableElement2 = document.getElementById("employeeList2");

for(var i=0,len=testData.length; i<len; i++){
    tableRow = document.createElement("tr");
    
    for(var k in testData[i]){
        rowCell = document.createElement("td");
        rowCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(testData[i][k]));
        tableRow.appendChild(rowCell);
    }
    
    tableBody.appendChild(tableRow);
}

tableElement2.appendChild(tableBody);
```

Pros:

- 2nd fastest execution time across Firefox/Chrome/Safari **(5 to 12 millisec across browsers)**. Measured via both performance.now() and console.time() APIs.
- More maintainable than 1st Approach

Cons:

- Execution time is more in IE browsers, **90+ millsec**

***3rd Way: Using Jquery to create DOM*** (My advise is don't use it)

```js
var tableBody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
var tableElement2 = document.getElementById("employeeList2");

for(var i=0,len=testData.length; i<len; i++){
    tableRow = $("<tr></tr>");
    
    for(var k in testData[i]){
        rowCell = $("<td></td>");
        rowCell.append(testData[i][k]);
        tableRow.append(rowCell);
    }
    
    tableBody.append(tableRow);
}

tableElement2.append(tableBody);
```

Pros:

- Easy to add attributes/class/styles on elements and is easy to read and maintainable.

Cons:

- Worst execution time across all browsers **(220 ms to 330 ms)**, slowest numbers are in IE

Answer (score 3):

You can try doing an AJAX fetch of the static HTML block instead of storing it in the page itself. It allows you to be more flexible with what kind of block you want to insert in the future as well.

Alternatively (this is just a random idea which and not very well fleshed out), you can store the "structure" as JSON data and then dynamically parse it. Possibly something like `{"div": {"div": {"span": "Text here"}}}` for `<div><div><span>Text here</span></div></div>`. I'd still go with AJAX though. :)

Comment: Hadn't thought of storing it on the server... I suppose I could make a JSP fragment for it and retrieve that with AJAX. Hmm..

Answer (score 3):

Question was asked long long time ago. For modern day browsers using `innerHtml` property on the element is the most efficient way.

```js
// Either create a new element or select an existing one:
const el = document.querySelector('#app');

el.innerHTML = `
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</li>
  <li>Adipisci perspiciatis blanditiis recusandae praesentium!</li>
  <li>Libero, culpa similique. Laborum, tempore!</li>
  <li>Nobis ab tempora laboriosam laborum!</li>
  <li>Distinctio, a? Maiores, pariatur nihil.</li>
  <li>Ab vitae quibusdam tempore rem?</li>
  <li>Delectus veritatis exercitationem rem ipsam.</li>
  <li>Eveniet praesentium quasi provident dicta!</li>
  <li>Quae quis consequuntur perspiciatis omnis.</li>
  <li>Delectus similique doloribus consequatur quidem!</li>
</ul>
`;
```

Browser will create the elements. It is faster and cleaner than creating elements individually through iteration. You can add properties, events, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is another option, you can put the HTML right into the current html inside of hidden div like this:

```
<div id="hiddenContainer" style="display:none;">
    <div><table><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table></div>
</div>
```

And then in jquery, you can read it:

```
var elements = $("#hiddenContainer").html()
```

Comment: There are no (proper) multiline strings in JS.

Comment: @Flo can you elaborate on that? Or link?

Comment: I like this option to create a hidden object, select it, clone it, modify it and then append it..  Makes it very easy to unhide for styling purposes, easy to maintain IMO and its the option I'm going to end up using.  I don't have to have THE most optimum performance just yet, not for an MVP.... that can come later when the product it up and running..  thanks @Jiri for that suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for performance I would stick with the first version because in the second one everytime you are calling `$('<div>')` or `$('<table>')` you are creating a new jQuery Object and then call `.append()` which also another method call you do.
 I would go with the first one.

Comment: But is it faster than letting JQuery parse a huge string? I imagine that could be expensive too...

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure, It depends on how many elements you want to create ! But working with ajax would not be a good idea, because that would slow it down even faster. But why are you returning an jquery Object in that function ? return the string and it will also work !