# Creating HTML elements from JS let

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create multiple `span` elements with a `.` contained inside but have found that the code below creates 3 `.` but without `span`.

```js
let loadingDots = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
  const dot = document.createElement('span');
  loadingDots += dot.innerHTML = '.';
  document.body.appendChild(dot);
}
```

How can I fix the above code to output `HTML` from `loadingDots` as

```
<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>
```

To give more context as looking at the comments, this may be working correctly in some aspects.

The code is being used in a React `component` as

```
class ...

  render() {
    let loadingDots = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
      const dot = document.createElement('span');
      dot.innerHTML = '.';
      loadingDots += dot.outerHTML;
    }

    return (
      <Fragment>
        {loadingDots}
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

The current `return` element of `loadingDots` is `...`

The other method I tried was to

```
let loadingDots = '';
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i += 1) {
  loadingDots += '<span>.</span>';
}
```

but this returned as `"<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>"` instead of `<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>`

Comment: I converted your code block into a code snippet in order to test your code faster. It seems to me that's perfectly working. If you check the generated HTML, it gives your three `<span>.</span>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to create large static DOM elements in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9614932/best-way-to-create-large-static-dom-elements-in-javascript)

Comment: I copied your code and run on my browser. It does generate 3 `<span>.</span>`.

Comment: As others have mentioned, there are 3 spans with a single dot appended to the body. But It's unclear to me what the `loadingDots` variable is for. That one will contain 3 dots without span, but you seem not to use it.

Comment: Thank you @KévinBibollet. I have updated the question to include the scenario and explain my question better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think my issue was because I was using within a React `component`.

I found the solution here [Functions as Children](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#functions-as-children) within the React documentation on `jsx`.

```
const LoadingDots = props => {
  const items = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < props.numTimes; i += 1) {
    items.push(props.children(i));
  }
  return <span>{items}</span>;
};
```

and then inside the `jsx` component

```
<LoadingDots numTimes={3}>
  {index => <span key={index}>.</span>}
</LoadingDots>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the variable assignment `dot.innerHTML = "."` returns the value (`.`), and that is used in the +=. So that line is equal to:

```
loadingDots += ".";
```

Do it in two lines:

```
dot.innerHTML = ".";
loadingDots += dot.outerHTML;
```

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this prior but it was returning `"<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>"` instead of `<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>`