# createElement inner HTML error in IE8

Tags: javascript, innerhtml, createelement

The following code works in all browser but IE8 and below.

```
            // Create Paragraph
            var para1 = document.createElement('p');
            var htmlstring = '<div style="width: 300px; font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 6pt; color: #FF0000;">'
            htmlstring = htmlstring + '<table style="width: 300px; font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 6pt; color: #FF0000;">'
            htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tr><td style="width: 100px;"><strong>ID</strong></td><td style="width: 200px;">' + ID + '</td></tr>';
            htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tr><td><strong>Date/Time</strong></td><td>' + DateStamp + '</td></tr>';
            htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tr><td><strong>Location</strong></td><td>' + Location + '</td></tr>';
            htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tr><td><strong>Event</strong></td><td>' + Event + '</td></tr>';
            htmlstring = htmlstring + '<tr><td><strong>Speed</strong></td><td>' + Speed + '</td></tr></table></div>';
            para1.innerHTML = htmlstring;  << THIS IS GENERATING AN UNKNOWN ERROR
```

Any one have a solution or know even why this is happening?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: How doesn't it work? (What is the error message.) You can access it via the warning icon in the status bar in IE.

Comment: Do all of your used variables come out properly? Did you log and check the resulting String?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml

Comment: Remove `DIV` declaration from _htmlstring_. Or append `DIV` into `P` as `document.createElement("p").appendChild(document.createElement("div"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot of "problems" with `innerHtml` in IE8 and below, for example see this [document.getElementById().innerHtml + IE7 can cause problems](http://www.jamischarles.com/blog/documentgetelementbyidinnerhtml-ie7-can-cause-problems/).

The most safe solution is probably to set `innerHtml` of a div instead of a paragraph.

Comment: `p` is not listed in the set of elements who have a read-only `innerHTML` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533897(VS.85).aspx

Comment: It works on all browsers bar IE8 and lower so it's not my variables or script

Comment: Thanks Xharze,  

I changed the code to this;

  // Create Paragraph
                var para1 = document.createElement('p');
                var adiv = document.createElement('div');
                adiv.style.cssText = 'width: 300px; font-family: "Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; color: #000000;';

                ...

                adiv.innerHTML = htmlstring;

                // para1.innerHTML = htmlstring;
                para1.appendChild(adiv);