# what is the best way to create html elements and populate them on html page?

Tags: asp.net, html, dom, web

I have **html Page** with **js** file on the head.

when the js file run :

1. call ajax request to get data
2. the callback run js to create html elements and populate the page.

Is it better (performance) to have page with server side to take care for creating the html elements and populate the page?

Comment: Why use AJAX? Why not display the information using asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

But to answer your question... yes, it is better (performance-wise) to have the back-end generate the HTML.

It's bad practice though. Here are some reasons why:
[Advantages of createElement over innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml)