# How to add a text field when user click a add button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When user clicks the add button a new row appears which i did it with this code:

```
function generateRow() {
    var d = document.getElementById("add");
    d.innerHTML += "<p><input type='text' name='items'>";
}
```

However, when I type some data into the added text field and then click the add button again the data I typed in the other row disappears. Can someone tell me a better solution for the JavaScript. I don't mind jQuery if it works better. Advance thanks!

Comment: You are getting the same element each time and just replacing its contents. You need to append a new element to the DOM

Comment: Stephen thanks for explaining, i have got the solution from zlatin. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use createElement together with appendChild instead of innerHTML:
[Advantages of createElement over innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml)

Also read this comprehensive article about innerHTML disadvatages and alternatives:
http://slayeroffice.com/articles/innerHTML_alternatives/
Especially the section [[5a] Creating Multiple Elements](http://slayeroffice.com/articles/innerHTML_alternatives/#5a)

In your case it could be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function generateRow() {
   var d = document.getElementById("add");
   var p = document.createElement("p");
   var input = document.createElement("input");
   input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
   input.setAttribute('name', 'items');
   p.appendChild(input);
   d.appendChild(p);
}
</script>
```

Also see http://jsfiddle.net/bvLba/

Comment: So when i call the function it should be like this right?

<p><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="generateRow()"/></p>

Comment: It could be like that, yes. It is not the problem in the way that you called the function (you could keep it the same as it was with your original function). The problem is that when you use innerHtml, the browser recreates all the input elements every time you add a new one, so this results in the behaviour you observe.

Comment: AHHH okay i get what you are trying to say. Thanks, will try it out and get back.

Comment: Yes it works, thanks alot, i am a newbie so thanks for taking your time to explain to me :)

Comment: Zlatin i just wanted to ask u if u knew a way to make each new textfield a different name. For example, first text field name items1, second would be items2 etc.

The reason why i am asking is because, i want to add the items into my database, but if it has the same name i cant. Is there anyway i can control the name for each text field?

Comment: Yes, just add a counter variable and merge it with 'items' string when the setAttribute method is called for the 'name' attribute

Comment: Okay can i decided to use an array so that the name all will be same and it will still work when i call back the data. Thanks again for your help.