# How do I populate a SELECT tag with many options without delays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm attempting to populate a select tag like so, using jquery, the range I'm choosing is actually pulled from a database but this simplifies things for you:

```
 var select_tag = $("select");
 for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
 {
      $("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>").appendTo(select_tag);
 }
```

When I do this, the code take quite awhile to run and populate the select tag. So much so that a user might start to think that their browser closed and start clicking everywhere. Is there anyways I can speed the process up/optimize it so that it doesn't take this long?

Please note that the select tag itself is added to the page based on a click event, and is not loaded with the webpage right away. In this example a user is on one page, then the user clicks the 'Next' button, this triggers various functions one of which adds and populates the select element to the DOM. I just need a way to speed-up or optimize the process.

Comment: just build first the html code and append it in just one call

Comment: you could set a first <option> directly inside your <select> and remove it when your data is loaded

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution.

```
var options = "";
 for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
 {
     options += "<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>";          
 }
 $("select").append(options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there are many "macro" optimizations you can make.
There are a few smaller optimizations you can make, though.

1. Avoid parsing HTML -- create elements using `document.createElement('option')`.
   See [Advantages of createElement over innerHTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml)
2. Use a `DocumentFragment` to batch-insert all options at once.
   See http://jsperf.com/document-fragment-vs-innerhtml-vs-looped-appendchild

Here's some sample code that does this:

```
var select_tag = $("select");
var docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
{
  docFrag.appendChild(createOption(i, i));
}
select_tag.append(docFrag);

function createOption(text, value) {
    // Avoid parsing HTML using jQuery; use native methods instead:
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = text;
    option.setAttribute('value', value);
    return option;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the element from the document and add all the elements, then insert it back into the document.

```
var select_tag = $("select").detach();

 for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
 {
      $("<option value='" + i + "'>" + i + "</option>").appendTo(select_tag);
 }

$('#orignal-location').append(select_tag);
```

Answer (score 0):

With Huge data there is always delay . So I recommend you to use another approach, like server filtering service  with a client side control such as  [select2](http://select2.github.io/) or [chosen](https://github.com/ksykulev/chosen-ajax-addition) jquery plugins to handle user input

Take a look at at these 2 they have remote data loading feature .

I hope this can help.