# Javascript get "this" class with onClick function

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function which manipulates an element with a specific class.
So far I have this:

```
function myFunc() {
var ball = document.getElementsByClassName('ball');
var myBall = 0;

myBall = ball[0].innerHTML; // HERE I NEED TO GET THE CURRENT BALL CLICKED

myBall[0].innerHTML = ++nr; // THE SAME HERE

}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to get the exactly div with the class:ball which was clicked. I know that myBall[0] is wrong. I need to set somehow the number representing the element clicked.

My HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="ball" onclick="myFunc()">1</div>
    <div class="ball" onclick="myFunc()">1</div>
    <div class="ball" onclick="myFunc()">1</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use `addEventListener`, problem solved !

Comment: @adeneo I don't really know how to do that. Can you show me an example? Thank you

Comment: How are you calling your split function (BTW, bad name choice for a function as JS already has one)? What's your HTML look like?

Comment: @j08691 I've added my HTML. I also changed the split to myFunc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this

```js
var elems = document.querySelectorAll('#container .ball');
    
for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    elems[i].addEventListener('click', myFunc, false);
}
    
function myFunc() {
  
    this.innerHTML = parseInt(this.innerHTML, 10) + 1;
    
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="ball">1</div>
    <div class="ball">2</div>
    <div class="ball">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why I have to add for each an event listener? How it knows now what element I am clicking?

Comment: Because that's the proper way to do it, unless you have a deLorean and can go back to 1997, when inline event handlers was fine.

Comment: Came here to post this.  Nice job.  Here's my fiddle of almost the same thing: http://jsfiddle.net/jasonwilczak/tx2aqg4x/1/

Comment: What if I want to add more "balls" while the script is running? Maybe have a button which adds another ball.

Comment: @FlorinPop I believe that is a pretty well known question that you could find in this site.  Here is a 'best practice' type post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml