# How to create and add elements to the DOM in a loop

Tags: javascript, html

I want to append `num` amount of `img` elements to the DOM, and give each image an `id` according to which `num` it is. I know I need a loop, so this is what I have so far:

```js
window.onload = function makeImage(){
  for(i=0;i<num;i++){  
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="<img id='i' src='img/image.jpg'/>";
  }
};
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Create Image object and append it to container as a child node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem here is you are not appending images in loop, old image just get overridden by the new one. Since you are using `=` operator.

```
document.getElementById('test').innerHTML="<img id='i' src='img/image.jpg'/>";
-----------------------------------------^
```

Use `+=` instead, also you need to concat `i` value to get image unique ids:

```js
var html = "";
var num = 3
for (var i = 1; num >= i; i++) {
  html += '<img src="http://www.tatwellness.com/store/image/cache/data/homewelcome/no%20image-200x200.png" id="img' + i + '"/>';
}

document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = html;
```

```css
img {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some code snippets and comments that should help you. Where you have `id='i'`, it looks like you want this: `'<img id="'+i+'"'`. You concatenate in JavaScript using the `+` sign, so close your string with a quote, then concatenate, then open the string up again. It's easier to learn by breaking this up into steps. Here's the string without the value: `'<img id=""'` Then, you'll need to go in between the double quotes and close and open the string with single quotes, and concatenate `i`, so this: `'+i+'`. Altogether, you get `'<img id="'+i+'"'`

```js
var num = 2;
// addEventListener is better practice than onload
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  // get the element reference before the loop (no need to repeat this)
  var testElem = document.getElementById('test');
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    // create an img element, this is better practice than using innerHTML
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = "//placehold.it/100x100";
    img.id = 'image'+i;
    testElem.appendChild(img);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

You could also use `innerHTML` by concatenating the new image as in the following example, but this has drawbacks. [Read more about createElement vs innerHTML here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml).

```js
var num = 2;
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var testElem = document.getElementById('test');
  for(i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    testElem.innerHTML+= '<img id="image'+i+'"src="//placehold.it/100x100">';
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: i got some questions. <img src="//placehold.it/100x100">'

Comment: i got some questions there. in this code of  '<img src="//placehold.it/100x100">' , what's the meaning of ''//placehold.it' and "/100X100"? is it format of this sentense?

Comment: @XinZhao I don't know what you're asking. It's just a url. It's irrelevant. I just used that url for the demo. Put whatever you want.

Comment: @XinZhao If my answer solved your problem, don't forget to accept it by clicking the checkmark underneath the voting arrows to the left of the answer. Some new people don't know about that. Check out the tour if you haven't already: http://stackoverflow.com/tour Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: it works. but I wanna keep image's id. for example, var num=2.

Comment: so that <img id=0> <img id=1> two pictures on this screen but different id but same picture