# How to add a new Image every few seconds in a innerHTML tag without breaking "<br>" JavaScript, HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a basic game with ledges you jump on, its always something i wanted to figure out. But my question is, I am using a innerHTML tag to insert a new image every few seconds, but when I do it breakes `<br>` by itself. How do you add a new image in a innerHTML tag without breaking?

```
function landT() {
    document.getElementById("land01").innerHTML += "<pre><img src =\'images/platform00.png\'></pre>";
    moveMYP();
}

function moveMYP() {
    var thisTimer = setTimeout(moveMYP, 500);
    moveBlock1 = moveBlock1 - 10;
    document.getElementById("land00").style.left = moveBlock1 + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your images are inside the `pre` which is **block element**.

You can modify the `display` CSS property to `inline` or redesign your code to not use the `pre` tag.

Have you considered using `createElement` function instead of the `innerHTML`? The difference is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2947012/5508582)

Comment: I am using the createElement but the image refuses to show.

Comment: var block00 = document.createElement("img");
 block00.src = "images/platform00.png";
 block00 = new Image();

Comment: @SNLippold You are creating a new element but you don't adding it to the document's DOM. After these lines add something like this: `document.getElementById("land01").appendChild(block00);`