# Optimizing usage of document.createElement?

Tags: javascript

```
function fooBar() {
  var creation = document.createElement('div');
  creation.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
}
```

So up there is a pretty ugly scenario. I often encounter moments where I just want to reuse one of these by cloning or whatever. Im not sure if im overthinking this but something just doesnt seem right. Is it possible to optimize this code?

Comment: if you want cloning, then just use it, there is a [`node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) method.

Comment: @Kaiido below the user used innerHTML but shouldnt innerHTML be avoided?

Comment: You talk about security reasons, but the only concerns would come if you do append some user's input or from untrusted sources. What is IMO bad in this habit of using innerHTML is that you are asking the browser to re-parse the string, which is, if I do remember correctly, slower than using the DOM for creating nodes. Also, if you do need to get the created node, you'll make an other call to a DOM method (such as `querySelector`) which would be avoided with well written node creation.

Comment: @Kaiido great info and upvoted.

Comment: @Kaiido http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml

Comment: accepted answer is great, but you're in none of its cases. However the question is quite old and I'm not sure e.g  Pekka's answer is still right about the speed : https://jsperf.com/clonenode-vs-createelement-performance/32 On my machine, cloneNode is way faster than any other method, and also, in my codes, I think it's clearer.

Comment: @Kaiido I actually chose cloneNode as the solution due to that reason. I really think it is elegant

Comment: @Kaiido you should post this as an answer. You got some really high quality content there. I think it deserves to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than continuing conversation in comments, I will simply post an answer.

#### Short Answer:

It doesn't matter in the slightest.

#### Longer Answer:

If by optimization you mean execution time, the difference is irrelevant unless you are creating 1000's of elements. If by optimization you mean good DRY code, then I would say your entire approach is incorrect: use templating instead.

The number of possible methods of templating make enumerating them beyond the scope of this answer, but anything from PHP (if that's how you roll) to Handlebars to custom regex replacements will get the job done. But about the only time I call `document.createElement` is for concurrent script bootstrapping that maintains execution order: see [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/script-loading/) for more details.

So to summarize, use re-usable templates. If the items need to be created dynamically then use client-side rendering. For everything else, use server-side rendering. Avoid manually creating elements as that's pretty low-level, prefer more abstract solutions like the one I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

how about this one

```
var creation = document.createElement('div');
creation.innerHTML = "<div></div>";
```

to get the element

```
el = creation.querySelector("div");
```

Comment: It uses innerHTML. I prefer to avoid it. Unless im missing out some information.

Comment: As far as im aware innerHTML should be avoided due to security concerns.

Comment: I think the appendChild can't be further optimized, how about use jQuery for better syntax looks?

Comment: Ya jquery could do the job but then I have 1000000 lines of extra code just for this one feature hehe. I prefer vanilla js because that : )

Comment: @Asperger `innerHTML` is fine. How could it possibly be a security concern if you are supplying the content yourself?

Comment: @Asperger You can use `innerHTML` with trusted strings, avoid it with user generated strings

Comment: I remember there were a few that told me to avoid it at all cost which is why I have been kind of of reluctant

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml

Comment: @Asperger if all HTML inside the string which proposed to being innerHTMLed is not entered by user, then innerHTML is safe

Comment: @Asperger that question and its answers are ***5 years old***. In any form of software development but *especially* web dev where everything changes much faster take anything that old with a *very* large grain of salt. Even if the technology doesn't change, best practices do.

Comment: @JaredSmith Oh I see. I didnt know that. So dont the points apply anymore?

Comment: @JaredSmith you're so right about the question's age, but it actually seem to have gone against innerHTML lately https://jsperf.com/clonenode-vs-createelement-performance/32

Comment: @Asperger, no the points made in the accepted answer are still correct and should still be thought of when we do **modify** the innerHTML of an element

Comment: @Kaiido which we dont. We just add new elements. Which doesnt make it the perfect solution for the job? Looking at the test within the link you supplied it seems pretty obvious that cloneNode is the candidate

Comment: @Asperger both `createElement` and `cloneNode` needs lots of lines to instantiate the elements, also `cloneNode` requires `createElement` as well before cloning, in the benchmark the div already created before benchmark starts, so `cloneNode` faster than `createElement`. If you wants performance you might go for `createElement`, but if you don't want too much `createElement` in your code, `innerHTML` is your choice