# Is it possible to insert child tags into an <option> element using innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, dom, innerhtml

The project I work on uses Mustache templates that are rendered into the page using jQuery's `html()` method.

I noticed that when my template is added to the page, the nodes I wrote inside an `<option>` tag are replaced by their inner text. However, this doesn't happen when building my page using DOM methods such as `createElement`, `appendChild`, etc.

I am aware that [option elements only accept text as content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option). But I am only using `<select>` to have it replaced with a custom form control that copies the `innerHTML` of each `<option>` into a `<div>`.

This snippet emulates the same behaviour:

```js
// using DOM methods:
var select = document.createElement('select'),
  option = document.createElement('option'),
    strong = document.createElement('strong'),
    withDOM = document.getElementById('dom-methods'),
    withInnerHTML = document.getElementById('inner-html'),
    exampleHTML = '<select><option><strong>Hello</strong></option></select>';
    

strong.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Hello'));
option.appendChild(strong);
select.appendChild(option);
withDOM.appendChild(select);
withDOM.appendChild(
 document.createTextNode(select.innerHTML)
);

// using innerHTML
withInnerHTML.innerHTML = exampleHTML;
withInnerHTML.appendChild(
 document.createTextNode(withInnerHTML.innerHTML)
)
```

```css
select { display: block }
```

```html
<h2>Using DOM methods</h2>
<p id="dom-methods"></p>
<h2>Using innerHTML</h2>
<p id="inner-html"></p>
```

Comment: Not certain what expected result is?

Comment: I expect the resulting elements to have identical content but using innerHTML results on the `<strong>` tag to be lost.

Comment: By the first sight I would say that there are different things going on when you work with innerhtml and document.createElement... I beleive working with document.createElement you say to the document to do something for you instead of just giving an string as in innerHtml that would eventually be a tag... Here is some other things about it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml

Comment: What is the purpose of trying to set `<strong>` element within `<option>` element ? Permitted content of [`<option>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) element is text. _"Permitted content Text with eventually escaped characters (like &eacute;)."_

Comment: @guest271314 in our case the `<option>` is turned into a `<a>` inside another element that "replaces" the `<select>`.

Comment: You could use `css` `a {font-weight:bold}` for this?

Comment: You will probably fair better using a [`<template>` element](http://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-scripting.html#the-template-element) than a `<select>` as your starting point.

Comment: I could make it work with a {{<datalist>}} which, in a way is more semantically closer to what I am looking for :) -- However, I wish I could use a {{<select>}} with options