# Add a radio inside .Innerhtml

Tags: javascript, checkbox, radio-button, innerhtml

I am trying to add a radio/checkbox inside the .innerHTML for a program in JavaScript. Is there a way to add a radio box/checkbox inside a .Innerhtmljavascript
codes Innerhtml part:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "I need a radiobox here";
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass the html code for the radio button..

```
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '<input type="radio" />'
```

Comment: Thanks..I got my mistake

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<input id='radiobutton' type='radio' >text</input>";
```

```html
<div id="demo" >
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks A Ton I tried the same thing but did not know how that a " " was needed for the code..again thanks

Answer (score 0):

instead of `innerHTML`, a better way to insert a new element into your Document

### Element.appendChild

```js
var radio = document.createElement("input");
radio.type = "radio";
radio.name = "r1";
document.querySelector("#demo").appendChild(radio);
```

```html
<label id="demo"></label>
```

### Element.insertAdjacentHTML

```js
document.querySelector("#demo").insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend",
  "<input type='radio' name='r1'>"
);
```

```html
<label id="demo"></label>
```

Available insertion points: `'beforebegin' 'afterbegin' 'beforeend' 'afterend'`

`innerHTML` will rewrite your target Element content, losing previous input states and attached events etc. [Read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml)

Comment: Thanks...I will get rid of innerhtml got it