# Issue dynamically generating table

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener

I am making a table using jquery, where the ids of the tiles are generated using a nested FOR loop. I am trying to add and event listener to the tiles, using their ids, so I can run a function when clicking them. However, the id, stored in the variable boatStatusClient is not recognised, and throws an error. Can anyone see the problem?

```
for (y_client = 1; y_client < 11; y_client++) {
    battlefield_client += "<tr>";
    for (x_client = 1; x_client < 11; x_client++) {
        battlefield_client += "<td onclick = '' class = 'tile' style='border: 3px solid black;' id=" + "cell_client_" + x_client + "_" + y_client + "><pre>     </pre></td>";
        boatStatusClient = document.getElementById('cell_client_' + x_client + "_" + y_client);
        console.log(boatStatusClient);
        boatStatusClient.addEventListener("click", function(){boatGrid.placeBoat_client()});
    }
    battlefield_client += "</tr>";
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tableGrid_client").html(battlefield_client); //loads table
```

Comment: add whole code in snipped so we can see the error

Comment: what's the error ? because I can see multiple problems in your code.
`declare variable before concat`
`can not add listner to null element`

Comment: we need to see what `document.getElementById('cell_client_' + x_client + "_" + y_client);` outputs. If it's null, you can't add an event listener. And why half pure JS, half jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, your event function is executing before of the DOM Element be created!

Try this:

```
for (y_client = 1; y_client < 11; y_client++) {
    battlefield_client += "<tr>";
    for (x_client = 1; x_client < 11; x_client++) {
        battlefield_client += "<td onclick = '' class = 'tile' style='border: 3px solid black;' id=" + "cell_client_" + x_client + "_" + y_client + "><pre>     </pre></td>";
    }
    battlefield_client += "</tr>";
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tableGrid_client").html(battlefield_client); //loads table
    $('.tile').click(function() {
        boatGrid.placeBoat_client();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed the problem

Comment: @MaximWebb If the answer solved your problem, mark it as a solution, so that other people are also helped!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your trying to find an element with document.getElementById() that does not exist in the DOM.

First append it to the page then search and add the relevant event listenrs.

But, you should really think of doing it with document.createElement (or jQuery objects) instead of concating strings. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml) for a more in-depth discussion.

Answer (score 0):

As fistuks already mentioned, you're trying to reach an element that is not yet in the DOM, and therefor you can't get it.

By doing this:

```
battlefield_client += "<td onclick = '' class = 'tile' style='border: 3px solid black;' id=" + "cell_client_" + x_client + "_" + y_client + "><pre>     </pre></td>";
```

You only make a string that holds this, but you never insert it into the dom - well at least not before you try to get that actual element.

So what you want to do is: append this string to the view/dom :-) 
Then you should be able to get it with your above method.

Besides that I would consider placing quotes better, and not mix the use of single- and doublequotes. My suggestion would be to always use single quotes when writing JavaScript, and double quotes when writing html.