# Which method is better/ faster for performance - createElement or innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making divs with several sub elements something like this:

```
<div class="item" data-id="28">
    <div class="action-btns">
        <button class="add"></button>
        <button class="rmv"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
        <h3>Title here</h3>
        <span>caption here</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And im giving functions to those two buttons on click. I'm wondering which method of creating these items is better - **createElement** *or* **innerHTML**?

As far as **createElement** goes i like it because i can bind the onclick while creating the button inside the element and then append it. Also im wondering if appending this "item" to the parent div is faster / better than updating innerHTML += "something";

As far as **innerHTML** goes there are fewer lines of code to write, but also i have to either write the onclick="myFunction()" inside the buttons instead of adding it dynamically.

Please no jQuery or anyting but pure Js. Thanks for your time ***:)***

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several advantages to using createElement instead of modifying innerHTML (as opposed to just throwing away what's already there and replacing it) besides safety, like Pekka already mentioned:

**Preserves existing references to DOM elements when appending elements**

When you append to (or otherwise modify) innerHTML, all the DOM nodes inside that element have to be re-parsed and recreated. If you saved any references to nodes, they will be essentially useless, because they aren't the ones that show up anymore.

**Preserves event handlers attached to any DOM elements**

This is really just a special case (although common) of the last one. Setting innerHTML will not automatically reattach event handlers to the new elements it creates, so you would have to keep track of them yourself and add them manually. Event delegation can eliminate this problem in some cases.

**Could be simpler/faster in some cases**

If you are doing lots of additions, you definitely don't want to keep resetting innerHTML because, although faster for simple changes, repeatedly re-parsing and creating elements would be slower. The way to get around that is to build up the HTML in a string and set innerHTML once when you are done. Depending on the situation, the string manipulation could be slower than just creating elements and appending them.

Additionally, the string manipulation code may be more complicated (especially if you want it to be safe).

Here's a function I use sometimes that make it more convenient to use createElement.

```
function isArray(a) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(a) === "[object Array]";
}

function make(desc) {
    if (!isArray(desc)) {
        return make.call(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
    }

    var name = desc[0];
    var attributes = desc[1];

    var el = document.createElement(name);

    var start = 1;
    if (typeof attributes === "object" && attributes !== null && !isArray(attributes)) {
        for (var attr in attributes) {
            el[attr] = attributes[attr];
        }
        start = 2;
    }

    for (var i = start; i < desc.length; i++) {
        if (isArray(desc[i])) {
            el.appendChild(make(desc[i]));
        }
        else {
            el.appendChild(document.createTextNode(desc[i]));
        }
    }

    return el;
}
```

If you call it like this:

```
make(["p", "Here is a ", ["a", { href:"http://www.google.com/" }, "link"], "."]);
```

you get the equivalent of this HTML:

```
<p>Here is a <a href="http://www.google.com/">link</a>.</p>
```

The answer of [@Matthew Crumley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml)

Comment: it's just copy-paste of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml

Comment: The answer of @Matthew Crumley

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest oh. I searched for this but it dodn't show it. (the question / answer). I assume the phrasing of the question was different enough to not find it.

Answer (score 3):

https://jsperf.com/innerhtml-vs-createelement-test (Note i did not write this)

Results in chrome is about 60% ish percent slower using createElement. As per (@Sagar V and @Hajji Tarik) answer consider more then just speed.

Comment: so according to this it is much fatser to use innerHTML?

Comment: InnerHtml is faster because you put a string in innerHTML = ... then the browser will translate it on html, but the createElement creates a html node that you can link events

Comment: from a pure speed perspective. yes. Similar results in Edge also.

Comment: I recommend the use of createElement if you are doing treatments on these elements

Comment: I'm confused. i also have to think about animations. I'm dynamically loading in elements and want them to have an animation when they load in. So whenever i used innerHTML it reanimated all of them. So in this case createElement is better since i can bind functions keep references and animate only the last loaded in elements?

Comment: Preserves event handlers attached to any DOM elements

This is really just a special case (although common) of the last one. Setting innerHTML will not automatically reattach event handlers to the new elements it creates, so you would have to keep track of them yourself and add them manually. Event delegation can eliminate this problem in some cases.

Comment: I think we would need more code to get a grasp of what you are doing to make more informed advice.

Answer (score 1):

`innerHTML` just put the plain text. Whereas `createElement` creates the element object and adds to Parent.
since browser convert tags in plain text to HTML element, it is converted to tags. It is not recommended.

`createElement` is the recommended method

Comment: Thanks :)  do you happen to know if updating innerHTML of a parent refreshes everything while appendChild only the last element? At least it seem so to me.

Comment: But it may misbehave in some old browsers