# How to reorder columns with Knex?

Tags: javascript, sqlite, electron

I am pulling all of my data from an Sqlite3 table using Knex, electron and JavaScript and I wish to reorder the columns either on the Knex query or in the HTML/JavaScript side.

My sqlite3 db has the following header data:

```
id|Role|Password|Reference
```

With the following code, the table displays in the following order:

```
Password|Reference|Role|id
```

I have attempted to utilize the .orderBy method in Knex and have also attempted to reorder in JavaScript, but I cannot seem to reorder the columns.

The Electron side of things, I have:

```
ipcMain.on('getUserTable:all', (event) => {
  let getUserTable = 
knex('User').select(['id','Role','Reference','Password']).orderBy('Role');
  getUserTable.then(function(tableData){
    newWin.webContents.send("userResultSent", tableData);
  });
});
```

In the HTML side of things, I have:

```
ipc.on('userResultSent', (event, tableData) => {
    var html = '<table>';
    html += '<tr>';
    for( var j in tableData[0] ) {
        html += '<th>' + j + '</th>';
        }
    html += '</tr>';
    for( var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr>';
            for( var j in tableData[i] ) {
            html += '<td>' + tableData[i][j] + '</td>';
        }
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('db_output_container').innerHTML = html;
});
```

I wish to be able to query the db so that the array displays in the exact order as in the table.

Comment: Objects do not have any order of properties. You need to send this information as an array within `tableData` or somehow else. `for( var j in tableData[0] ) {
        html += '<th>' + j + '</th>';
        }` might be implementation dependent and not guaranteed. From MDN "A for...in loop iterates over the properties of an object in an arbitrary order"

Comment: `orderBy` refers to the order of objects in resultset not the order of properties. Because @see above

Comment: So you are suggesting that I create an array from the array passed in from Sqlite3?

Comment: No I suggest to send column order as metadata `newWin.webContents.send("userResultSent", {columns: ['id', 'Role' and so on], tableData})` and the loop over columns instead of object properties. This would guarantee the order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your current approach is that object are unordered bags of properties. So it does not matter how order your columns - properties order is not guaranteed.

If you need specific order you could use `Array` instead.

Since you have general code to display tabular data you could do the following

```
ipcMain.on('getUserTable:all', (event) => {
  const columns = ['id','role','reference','password']

  let getUserTable = 
knex('User').select(columns).orderBy('role');
  getUserTable.then(function(tableData){
    newWin.webContents.send("userResultSent", {columns, tableData});
  });
});
```

When creating html

```
ipc.on('userResultSent', (event, {columns, tableData}) => {
    var html = '<table>';
    html += '<tr>';

    columns.forEach(column => {
        // if you want to capitalize names just do it here
        html += '<th>' + column + '</th>';
    })

    html += '</tr>';
    for( var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr>';
        columns.forEach(column => {
          html += '<td>' + tableData[i][column] + '</td>';
        })

        html += '</tr>'; 
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('db_output_container').innerHTML = html;
  })
```

Comment: I think this may work, I will give it a shot tomorrow, thank you!

Comment: Sorry for the delay, this works perfectly, thank you so much!!  Lesson learned here big time.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the second for loop, you should close the tr tag. Indeed, you open it right after the second for loop but you don't close it.
I haven't tested yet but it should work.

Your html file should looks like this.

```
ipc.on('userResultSent', (event, tableData) => {
    var html = '<table>';
    html += '<tr>';
    for( var j in tableData[0] ) {
        html += '<th>' + j + '</th>';
        }
    html += '</tr>';
    for( var i = 0; i < tableData.length; i++) {
        html += '<tr>';
            for( var j in tableData[i] ) {
            html += '<td>' + tableData[i][j] + '</td>';
        }
        html += '</tr>'; /* i added this line here */
    }
    html += '</table>';
    document.getElementById('db_output_container').innerHTML = html;
});
```

Comment: Furthermore, it should be better to use createElement method in javascript instead of innerHTML. This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml) should help you

Comment: I appreciate your response, I have tested both ways and it is still closing the <tr> with </tr> on execution.  This is cleaner though, thanks for this.