# I have a problem with the h4 content extraction code

Tags: javascript

```js
  var geth4text = document.querySelector("#post > div > h4").innerHTML;
  var text = "";

var i;
for (i = 0; i < geth4text.length; i++) {
s = geth4text[i]


  text +=  "<li>"+s+"</li>";
}
for (i = 0; i < geth4text.length; i++) {

}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="post"><div> 
  <h4>Example 1</h4>
  <h4>Example 2</h4>
  <h4>Example 3</h4>
  <h4>Example 4</h4>
  <h4>Example 5</h4>
  </div></div>


<span>Example</span>
    <div id="demo"></div>
```

This code outputs all characters from or h4 content
I am trying to extract the whole sum as it is in the first formula but within the "`<li>`"

Answer (score 1):

`querySelector` returns the first element to match the query; `querySelectorAll`, on the other hand, returns all elements that match the query.

However, `querySelectorAll` returns an iterable but not an array, so we can use the `[...querySelectorAll('')]` spread operator to construct an array of the elements.

```js
var geth4text = [...document.querySelectorAll("#post > div > h4")].map(h4 => h4.innerText);
var text = "";

var i;
for (i = 0; i < geth4text.length; i++) {
 s = geth4text[i]


 text += "<li>" + s + "</li>";
}
for (i = 0; i < geth4text.length; i++) {

}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="post">
 <div>
  <h4>Example 1</h4>
  <h4>Example 2</h4>
  <h4>Example 3</h4>
  <h4>Example 4</h4>
  <h4>Example 5</h4>
 </div>
</div>


<span>Example</span>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use createElement/appendChild instead of .innerHTML whenever you can to boost performance:

```js
const list = document.getElementById('demo');
document.querySelectorAll('#post > div > h4').forEach(headline => {
   let listItem = document.createElement('li');
   listItem.innerText = headline.innerText;
   list.appendChild(listItem);
});
```

```html
<div id="post">
  <div> 
    <h4>Example 1</h4>
    <h4>Example 2</h4>
    <h4>Example 3</h4>
    <h4>Example 4</h4>
    <h4>Example 5</h4>
  </div>
</div>


<span>Example</span>
<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `querySelectorAll` rather than `querySelector` as we are querying for multiple elements. `querySelectorAll` returns a NodeList that (much like an array) exposes n `forEach` method that we can use to iterate the elements. Also you should use `document.appendChild` rather just setting `innerHTML` ([here's an explanation why](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2947012/3755425)).

```js
const demoEl = document.getElementById("demo");

document
  .querySelectorAll("#post > div > h4")
  .forEach(
    ({ innerHTML }) =>
      (demoEl.appendChild(document.createElement("li")).innerHTML = innerHTML)
  );
```

```html
<div id="post">
  <div> 
    <h4>Example 1</h4>
    <h4>Example 2</h4>
    <h4>Example 3</h4>
    <h4>Example 4</h4>
    <h4>Example 5</h4>
  </div>
</div>


<span>Example</span>
<ul id="demo"></ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply make tag of `#demo` a `ul` and not a `div`

Comment: I agree that you should use an `ul` rather than a `div` here, but that doesn't relate to OP's issue