# How can I render Images with JavaScript into my HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to render Images with JavaScript into my HTML-File. I can't find the problem, here is my code from the JavaScript and the HTML. Really appreciate when someone can help me.

Than you!

```
const imgs = [
    "images/p1.jpg",
    "images/p2.jpg",
    "images/p3.jpg"
]

const container = document.getElementById("container")

function renderImages() {
    let getImgs = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        getImgs = `<img scr="${imgs[i]}">`
    }
    container.innerHTML = getImgs
}

renderImages()



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <div id="container">

    </div>


    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What your script does is not what most people would consider "rendering images" (I was thinking you'd be drawing using `Canvas`)

Comment: Have you use your browser's JS debugger to investigate the problem? **If not, why not?**

Comment: You should avoid using `innerHTML` (it's slow and insecure: it opens you up to XSS vulnerabilities). Instead use `document.createElement` and `appendChild` to add new elements to the DOM.

Comment: @Dai `innerHTML` is insecure, yes, but it is faster than `document.createElement` especially if you build the HTML string then call `innerHTML` once.

Comment: the code you provided will only add "images/p3.jpg" to your container with 0 width and 0 height. try adding style to your image.

Comment: this will not work: `<img scr="${imgs[i]}">`  See here how to use template literals https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: You spelled wrong src attribute in img tag its 'src' not 'scr'

Comment: @slebetman The only benchmark I can find that shows `innerHTML` to be faster is the QuirksMode page from 2007 which only concerns building a table element ( https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/innerhtml.html ) so I’m not convinced. And even if it is faster, there any many other non-performance reasons for preferring `createElement` still: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2946656/advantages-of-createelement-over-innerhtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use an equal sign (`=`) rather than a plus-equal sign (`+=`). The plus-equal sign will add the text to the variable, while the equal sign will overwrite the variable.

This line:

```
        getImgs = `<img scr="${imgs[i]}">`
```

`getImgs` is being set to the string, the string is not being added to it. You need to change it to something like this:

```
        getImgs += `<img scr="${imgs[i]}">`
```

(Notice the plus before the equal sign)

This way, the variable will not be completely changed, rather it will be appended to.

Full code:

```js
const imgs = [
    "images/p1.jpg",
    "images/p2.jpg",
    "images/p3.jpg"
]

const container = document.getElementById("container")

function renderImages() {
    let getImgs = ""
    for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        getImgs += `<img scr="${imgs[i]}">`
    }
    container.innerHTML = getImgs
}

renderImages()
```

```css
/* I added css so you can see the images */
img {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, blue, green);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Headline</h1>
    <div id="container">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS was added just so you can see where the images are.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Now my code works and the images are loaded. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const imgs = [
    "images/p1.jpg",
    "images/p2.jpg",
    "images/p3.jpg"
]; // list of sources of images to be rendered

const container = document.getElementById("container"); // the element that is going to contain those images

const loadImage = url => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => resolve(img); // resolve the promise if the image has been successfully loaded
    img.onerror = () => reject(); // else reject the promise
    img.src = url; // set the source only after the event handlers have been set
  });
};

const renderImages = async () => {
   try {
     const loadedImages = await Promise.all(imgs.map(loadImage));
     const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
     frag.append(...loadedImages);
     container.appendChild(frag); 
   } catch {
     console.error("Couldn't render the images");
   }
};

renderImages();
```

here the `loadImage` function is used to load the images and it returns a promise that resolves only when the images have been loaded

then in the `renderImages` function we await until all the images have been loaded then we append all those images to a document fragment so to reduce the number of dom updates, then finally we append that document fragment to the container.

I hope it helps and please pardon my bad english.

Comment: I tried your code, and it will load the images. But I am very new into web development, so i cant fully understand your code. :D  My code works now, it was only a spelling mistake and a small mistake with = and +=. Thanks a lot for your help! Your English isn't bad, just saying :)

Answer (score 0):

With your code, the result is just one image tag(img):
[result with your code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uzWtK.png)

You must include the innerHTML inside of the loop:
[InnerHTML inside the loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p04pg.png)

And that's all.
[HTML result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8XLw.png)

Comment: It is better to put code and snippets in your answers, please, avoid using images, especially with code

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is go to your line inside your for loop:

```
getImgs = `<img scr="${imgs[i]}">`
```

And change it to

```
getImgs += `<img src="${imgs[i]}">`
```

**Errors:**

You had `scr="${imgs[i]}"` insead of `src="${imgs[i]}"`. (`src` instead of `scr`)

Another issue was getImgs `=`. That should be `+=`, because otherwise every time you are making getImgs equal the last img. With `+=`, you are adding a new image element to `getImgs` each time, so at the end of the loop `getImgs` contains all of the img tags.

### Another Route to Success

Instead you could rewrite your function to something like this:

```
function renderImages() {
    for (let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        container.innerHTML += `<img src="${imgs[i]}">`
    }
}
```

Which is perhaps more compact.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I just did not see the spelling mistake... Now everything works! Thank you very much!